# enviar datos a un json local mediante fetch api Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

Tengo un archivo json vacío y quiero llenarlo con los datos de un form, al hacer click sobre un botón enviar quiero que el correo que escribio el usuario en el input se envie a un archivo json local.

pero siempre obtengo:

> Response {type: "basic", url: "http://124.0.0.1:5501/data/users.json",
> redirected: false, status: 405, ok: false, …}
>
> statusText: "Method Not Allowed"

como puedo hacer para enviar los datos a ese archivo dentro de "users" ?
Gracias por la ayuda.

```
const suscribeUserForm = document.getElementById('correo');
    const btnGuardar = document.getElementById('btnGuardar');
    
    btnGuardar.addEventListener('click', function(){
      const suscribeUserFormValue = suscribeUserForm.value;
      fetch('../../data/users.json', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "aplication/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userEmail: suscribeUserFormValue
        })
      })
      .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
      }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      })
    })
```

En el json tengo

```
{
    "users": [
        
    ]
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: entonces si estas enviado datos no sabemos que datos estas almacenando en el json ni como los estas recibiendo... creo que tu ejemplo aunque da una idea le faltan mas detalles para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Pues el servicio te está diciendo que no admite peticiones POST. Habría que ver cómo está definido el servicio que intentas consumir...

Comment: Hola, es un archivo json que tengo en esta ruta ../../data/users.json, y quiero enviarle la data de un form, donde un usuario coloca su correo, no es ningún servicio externo, no se si se puede hacer algo así. o si puedo enviarle datos  userEmail: suscribeUserFormValue por post a un json que esta vacio aunque no se como declararlo

Comment: ¿Quieres modificar el archivo JSON con una petición AJAX? No se puede, tiene que haber un script del lado del servidor que lo lea, tome los datos del formulario, haga las actualizaciones necesarias y lo guarde nuevamente.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias